# SQL Server - multiple tables columns in 1 view and under 1 column header

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do the following:

I have 2 tables called `Holidays` and `Allocations`, both of which contain a `startDate` and `endDate` field. I want to create a view which will display the `startDate` and `endDate` fields from both of these tables, but under the same column headers if possible, can this be done? or do I need to create a single table to handle this?

My theory behind using a view is that this will avoid the 1 large table storing a lot more columns, of which will contain null's where certain fields are not required.

Comment: Without more information we can't comment on your design decision.  It is ***possible*** *(see below)* but there are many alternatives and currently it is impossible to say if your choice for you use-case is good or sensible, or not.  It feels like you should be able to normalise your design (more rows rather than columns), and that UNIONing two tables together seems like a code-smell to me.  But that's all conjecture without more information.

Comment: I am at the design phase currently and when normalized, the tables break down in a way that splits everything up. This is the best practice for my scenario, Before i progress i wanted to know if it was possible so I can create a calendar based of a view so when data is entered elsewhere, then all of this information can be displayed easily and if ammendments are made, then the calendar view would be updated.

Comment: `This is the best practice for my scenario` is a truly bold statement :)

Comment: haha ;) there are so many design approaches I could use to get my scenario working, I kept changing my mind and im finally sticking with one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in `view` by using `UNION`

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewHolidayAllocation]
AS

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum, 
    * 
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, startDate, endDate FROM Holidays
    UNION
    SELECT Id, startDate, endDate FROM Allocations
) AS result
```

Comment: perfect thankyou, this will make it a hell of a lot easier to manage!!

Comment: I recommend adding an additional field to indicate the source of the row *(as in this specific example, the IDs will likely not be unique)*

Comment: @MatBailie: Thanks for suggestion. I have modified my answer. :)

Comment: I have linked it to the staff's name, so therefore the union statement above now contains joins to my staff table

Answer (score 1):

You can't have column name duplicate in view. You have to normalize db if it has sense or you have to define alias to second field.